# Scala Standalone JAR with a conf Folder

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I'm using the sbt assembly jar plugin to create a standalone jar file. My project folder structure would look like this:

```
MyProject
 -src
   - main
     - scala
       - mypackages and source files
     - conf // contains application.conf, application.test.conf and so on
   - test
 -project // contains all the build related files
 - README.md
```

I now want to be able to run the fat jar that I produce against a version of the application.conf that I specify as a System property!

So here is what I do in my unit test!

```
System.setProperty("environment", "test")
```

And this is how I load the config in one of the files in my src folder:

```
val someEnv = Option(System.getProperty("environment", "")).filter(_.nonEmpty) // gives me some(test)
val name = s"application.${someEnv.get}.conf"
```

I can see that the environment variable is set and I get the environment passed it. But later on I load the application.test.conf as below:

```
ConfigFactory.load(name).resolve()
```

It however loads just the edfault application.conf and not the one that I specify!

What is wrong in my case? Where should I put the conf folder? I'm trying to run it against my unit test which is inside the test folder!

Comment: Is it really src/main/mypackages and src/main/conf? Shouldn't it be src/main/scala/mypackages and src/main/resources/ ?

Comment: Sorry about that! Good catch!

Comment: But that was not causing the actual problem

Comment: not even src/main/resources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Here is what I had to do! Change the name of the folder where the config file is located. I originally had it as conf and I had to rename it to resources and bang it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the full name of the configuration file. The `.conf` is optional. Try

```
ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${someEnv.get}").resolve()
```

[The docs](https://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory.html#load-java.lang.String-) for `ConfigFactory.load(String)` indicate you need to supply

> name (optionally without extension) of a resource on classpath

Comment: No! That was not a resolution. I was infact loading it already like you have posted, but it still would not pick it up!

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with the config returned? How do you know which config is being used? In the code above you're not doing anything with the result of `ConfigFactory.load(someEnv.get).resolve()`

Comment: I just posted the bits of my actual code and in the process, I messed up a little when posting it here! So now I have corrected my post, but the original problem is still there!

Comment: Are you baffled? If I unpack the jar file and run it, it works. But unpacking is not an option as this jar file will be submitted to a Spark server!